# Problem trying to use env variables in my severless.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I have a problem trying to use env variables in my severless.yml

I have an env.yml with the env var called `BUCKET_UPLOADS` which sits under `dev`

In the serveless.yml I am trying to use this variable like so:

`"arn:aws:s3:::${process.env.BUCKET_UPLOADS}/*"`

But when trying to deploy I get:

> Bucket name should not contain uppercase characters.

There are no capitols in the variable value so I think it's taking the above literally but as far as I can see it should be using the variable instead given the markup `${...}`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following rules apply for naming S3 buckets.

- Bucket names must be between 3 and 63 characters long.
- Bucket names can consist only of lowercase letters, numbers, dots
  (.), and hyphens (-).

> S3_HTML_TEMPLATES: ${self:service}-html-templates-s7adnjfnabbfvai7
> S3_LANGUAGE_TEMPLATES: ${self:service}-language-templates-12747dhadgdva
> S3_STATIC_WEBSITE: '${self:service}-static-website-asjdu29ehq1i2'

- Bucket names must begin and end with a letter or number.
- Bucket names must not be formatted as an IP address (for example,
  192.168.5.4).
- Bucket names can't begin with xn-- (for buckets created after
  February 2020).
- Bucket names must be unique within a partition. A partition is a
  grouping of Regions. AWS currently has three partitions: aws
  (Standard Regions), aws-cn (China Regions), and aws-us-gov (AWS
  GovCloud [US] Regions).
- Buckets used with Amazon S3 Transfer Acceleration can't have dots (.)
  in their names. For more information about transfer acceleration, see
  Amazon S3 Transfer Acceleration.

You can follow this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html#bucketnamingrules) to make it done. Thank's

Answer (score 0):

`${file(env.yml):${opt:stage}.BUCKET_UPLOADS}` was what I needed in the end.

I had misunderstood how the variables were being formed and fetched.